# Why when I start the docker container using default network it does not give data and when I start it using host network everything works fine?

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, networking, virtual-machine

1.I have an app based on Nodejs. When I run it in docker container and using default network the container does not give me any data. And when I use the host network everything works fine. Why is that so?

2. I have a machine with proxmox installed. Several virtual machines are running there. When I run the above application in docker, I cannot access the data externally through nginx.I turned off the general Firewall on the virtual machines on the main machine but that didn't help. For the experiment, I launch the aws ec2 and ran the above program in docker there and surprisingly I got a response from the container via nginx. Please tell me what the problem is?

VM - Linux Ubuntu 20.0.4 / 5.15.78-051578-generic

```
FROM node:18.12.1
#WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . ./

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Part of the code

```
const permisionMarket = await launchpad._signTypedData(domain, createMatrixType, {
    nonce: 1,
    buyer: BUYER_ADDRESS,
    uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/',
  });
  const permisionForCreateMatrix = await signForCreateMatrix(domain, 1, BUYER_ADDRESS, 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/', launchpad);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you *bind* your application to 127.0.0.1, that means that the application will only accept connections from the local machine. In a container, the local machine is the container itself. So your app will only accept connections from inside the container and not from the host.

Change

```
uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/',
```

to

```
uri: 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/',
```

to make the app accept connections from everywhere and you should be able to connect to it from the host.

Comment: Hans - Thanks! Yes you are right it makes sense but in my case it didn't help. Maybe you know why it works fine on ec2 but not on my virtual machine?